# Changing the frequency of a signal using Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, numeric

I want to change the frequency of a given oscillatory signal `y(t)` using Matlab.

---

Let's consider a sine signal as an example:

```
h = 0.01;         %step width
t = 0:h:2*pi;
y = sin(2*pi*t);
```

This generates a sine signal with a frequency of `1 Hz`, assuming `t` is measured in seconds.

Is it possible to change the frequency of the signal `y(t)` to an arbitrary frequency of `x Hz` without using `y = sin(2*pi*x*t)` (as the actual signal I want to change the frequency of isn't given analytically)?

---

What I actually want to do is comparing the signal form of signals with different frequencies by changing their frequency to a common one and overlay them. It is important that the different signals can be evaluated at the same time points.

Comment: Can you just use a common sampling metric of x Hz ?

Comment: For your sine example, adding the `x` in the sine equation is the only way to specify the frequency of your signal. It means you will pass `2*pi*x` radians in one second.

Comment: is your signal periodic? if it's not periodic, you can't change it to a higher frequency but just to a lower one since otherwise you are lacking information

Comment: if your signal is periodic and you just want to rescale it to higher frequencies this would be an easy first try: 
`y2=repmat(y,1,ceil(scaleFactor));
y2=y2(round(linspace(1,scaleFactor*length(y),length(y))));`   
If this doesn't help you will need to provide an example of the signals you are dealing with

Comment: you could try scaling the horizontal axis of your plot (i.e. time) by a different amount for each of your oscillatory signals? e.g. `hold all; plot(t,y1); plot(t/2, y2)`. Visually, it will have the same effect as doubling the frequency of y2.

Comment: Thank you all! I could solve it by using the `resample` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to perform frequency shifting. This topic is very old and you can find discussion in many places. E.g. https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/9996-1.php